# Replace null values in right outer join with a previous not null matched row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have this query

```
select a.WeekNumber
        ,a.filedate
        ,a.customer
        ,material
        ,Quantity
from zfmon zf right outer join zfmonTemp a
on zf.customer = a.customer
        and zf.filedate = a.filedate
        and zf.material =  'AD215BY'
```

It returns the following

```
WeekNumber FileDate                 Customer Material Quantity
1          2010-03-19 00:00:00.000  1008777  NULL     NULL
2          2010-03-12 00:00:00.000  1008777  AD215XX  3
```

What I want is for when the material is null replace it with the next not null value. In this case it would replace it with AD215XX

Therefore the output will look like

```
WeekNumber FileDate                 Customer Material Quantity
1          2010-03-19 00:00:00.000  1008777  AD215XX  NULL
2          2010-03-12 00:00:00.000  1008777  AD215XX  3
```

Is that possible to do? Can any one help please.

Thanks,
Eli

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.WeekNumber
        ,a.filedate
        ,a.customer
        ,isnull(material, (select top 1 material from zfmonTemp where weeknumber > zf.weeknumber and material is not null order by weeknumber)) material
        ,Quantity
from zfmon zf right outer join zfmonTemp a
on zf.customer = a.customer
        and zf.filedate = a.filedate
        and zf.material =  'AD215BY'
```

Comment: Probably need to lomit the subselect in case there is more than 1 row with a greater weeknumber?

Comment: Thanks for the response but this didnt work. weeknumber is not a field in zfmon but it is in zfmonTemp. Here is the table structures: Zfmon has (filedate,customer,material,quantity) and ZfmonTemp has (filedate, customer, weeknumber)

Comment: @Elias - Perhaps instead of `weeknumber`, use `filedate` in this answer?

Comment: Yea I tried this when you gave the first answer but it didnt work either

Answer (score 0):

```
set @material = 'AD215BY';
select a.WeekNumber
        ,a.filedate
        ,a.customer
        ,coalesce(zf.material, @material) as Material
        ,zf.Quantity
from zfmon zf right outer join zfmonTemp a
on zf.customer = a.customer
        and zf.filedate = a.filedate
        and zf.material = @material
```